# Estimate of the difference of initial conditions depending on the solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be compact and $u \mathbin{:}
>  (0,\infty)\times\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be of class $C^1$. Consider
>   the differential equation $$ \dot{x}=u(t,x), $$ $$ x(0)=y. $$

Then we have a unique solution $x=x(t,y)$. Moreover, we can invert $x$ with respect to $y$ and get a function $y=y(t,x)$.

So here goes the question. I found the following statement in one article (presented as an obvious observation) and I have some concerns about it.

> Suppose we have $u_1,u_2$ and respectively $y_1,y_2$ defined as above.
>   Then $$\|y_1(t,\cdot)-y_2(t,\cdot)\|_\infty \leq
>  \int_0^t \|u_1(s,\cdot)-u_2(s,\cdot)\|_\infty ds. $$

My attempt: from what I understand, taking $y(t,x)$ would mean "going back from $x$ to $y$". So then $y_i$ would satisfy the equation
$$ \dot{y}_i = -u_i(t,y_i), $$
$$ y_i(0) = x $$
and we get 
$$ |y_1(t,x)-y_2(t,x)|\leq \int_0^t |u_1(s,y_1)-u_2(s,y_2)| ds. $$
We can see that it's almost the same we need, but the arguments of $u_1$ and $u_2$ are different and it raises my concern. I suppose we could now use the Lipschitz continuity of $u_i$ and write
$$ |u_1(s,y_1)-u_2(s,y_2)|\leq |u_1(s,y_1)-u_1(s,y_2)|+|u_1(s,y_2)-u_2(s,y_2)| $$
$$\leq L|y_1-y_2|+\|u_1-u_2\|_\infty $$

and then apply Gronwall's lemma to finally get our bound with some constant. However this approach seems to be more complicated than necessary, so I would really appreciate if you could give me a more straightforward argument.

PS.: Please write me if the title is misleading, I didn't know how to precisely formulate it.

PS2.: Although this is and ODE problem, it emerged in the PDE setting in the method of characteristics, that's why I also tagged it as PDE.

Comment: Can you also link to the article that you are reading?

Comment: This statement is less detailed than using the Lipschitz continuity. It is just the FTC for the backward equation and then the triangle inequality.

Comment: Not sure why they are writing $u_1,u_2$ though. You really just want $\max_{y_1,y_2} \| u(s,y_1)-u(s,y_2) \|$. Or are you looking at two different ODEs in addition to two different ICs?

Comment: I have two flows $u_1$ and $u_2$, both of them starting from the same IC. So each of them gives us one solution $x_1(t,y)$ and $x_2(t,y)$ and after inversion we have the corresponding $y_1(t,x)$ and $y_2(t,x)$.

Comment: Later on I want to deduce that $\|y_1-y_2\|_\infty\to 0$ if $\|u_1-u_2\|_\infty\to 0$ and that's why I need this specific bound.

Comment: Actually now I'm not even sure if $y_i$ really satisfies $\dot{y}_i=-u_i(t,y_i)$....