# Can I reverse an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u\colon [0,T]\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be of class $C^1$. Consider the differential equation
$$ \dot{x} = u(t,x), $$
$$ x(0)=y. $$
Then we have a unique solution $x(t,y)$. Moreover, the matrix $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}$ is invertible, so we can write $y$ as a function of $x$.

Now the problem: I want to write an ODE satisfied by $y(t,x)$. My intuition tells me that to obtain $y$ from $x$ I need to "return back" on the same trajectory, and then my ODE would be
$$ \dot{y} = -u(t,y), $$
$$ y(0) = x. $$
However, I couldn't find a rigorous argument. Is this even true? If not, could you give me an counterexample?

This post is related to my previous question: [Estimate of the difference of initial conditions depending on the solutions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3693057/estimate-of-the-difference-of-initial-conditions-depending-on-the-solutions)

EDIT: It's not true. Let $u(t,x)=x+t$. Then the solution to
$$ \dot{x} = x+t, $$
$$ x(0)=y $$
is $x(t,y) = -(t+1)+(y+1)e^t$ and after writing $y$ in terms of $x$ we have $y(t,x) = (t+x+1)e^{-t}-1$. Then
$$ \dot{y} = -(t+x)e^{-t} \neq -u(t,y). $$
However, this led me to a new hypothesis, that
$$ \dot{y} = -u(t,x)\frac{dy}{dx}. $$

Comment: What you are asking in the edit is actually formalized in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917323/definition-of-the-flow-of-an-ode-and-its-inverse. I'm not sure if the formula there is true, as each IC $(t,x)$ with $x$ constant, $t$ varying gives a different solution, so its derivative is not purely along the vector field of the original equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to distinguish the independent variable of the equation and the fixed time where you consider the correspondence of initial point and final point. Name the latter time $T$, the points $x_0$ and $x_T$. Then to reverse the flow you have to consider the problem
$$
\dot x(t)=u(t,x(t)),~~ x(T)=x_T
$$
where you want to compute $x_0=x(0)$ backwards in time. If you want to integrate forward in time, you can consider the function $y(t)=x(T-t)$, which then has the differential equation
$$
\dot y(t)=-\dot x(T-t)=-u(T-t,x(T-t))=-u(T-t,y(t)),~~ y(0)=x_T.
$$

Comment: thanks for your comment! Actually I need to find the inverse at any $t$, so I do not have a final point. I believe that I could do something like define $y_t(s)=x(t-s)$, which will satisfy the equation you wrote with the initial condition $y_t(0)=x(t)$. Then I think that my $y(t,x)$ would be defined as $y(t,x)=y_t(t)$ and I have to differentiate it by $t$ to get an ODE for $y$?

Comment: Also thanks to your comment I found a counterexample to my statement, I will edit the main post.