# Definition of the flow of an ODE and its inverse

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

At lesson, the teacher considers a flow $\Phi$ given by the solutions of the ode system for $t\in[0, T]$ and $x\in\mathbb R^d$,
$$
\begin{cases}
y'(s)=b(y(s), s),&s\leq T\\
y(t)=x
\end{cases},\qquad(\star)
$$
that is $\Phi(x, t, s)=y(s)$ solving $(\star)$. He said that we will be mostly concerned with $\Phi(\cdot, 0, \cdot)$. The field $b$ is assumed to be Lipschitz continuous in both variables and bounded.

Then, he intoduces the inverse $\Psi$ of the above flow as follows: $\Psi(x, 0, s)=y(s)$ satisfying
$$
\begin{cases}
y'(s)=-b(y(s), t-s),&s<t\leq T\\
y(0)=x
\end{cases},\qquad(\triangle)
$$
and he said that $\Psi$ is such that
$$
\Phi(\Psi(x, 0, s), 0, s)=x,\quad \Psi(\Phi(x, 0, s), 0, s)=x.\qquad (\star\star)
$$
I do not understand $(\star\star)$. Can someone help me? Maybe is the definition of the inverse wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After @lutz-lehmann pointed out that my arguments would apply only to an autonomous system, I will try to make an analogous argument for the related autonomous system.

---

I will stick to the $t = 0$ case.

---

Let $s\mapsto\mathbf{u}(s) = [y(s),~s]^{\mathsf{T}}$ be the solution of
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{ds}\left[\begin{array}{c}y(s)\\s\end{array}\right] &=& \left[\begin{array}{c}b(y(s),s)\\1\end{array}\right] ~=~ \left[\begin{array}{c}b(\mathbf{u}(s))\\1\end{array}\right],\\
\mathbf{u}(0) &=& \left[\begin{array}{c}x\\0\end{array}\right].
\end{eqnarray}

Since $b$'s argument is $\mathbf{u}(s)$, this system is autonomous.

Let $U$ be the flow for this autonomous system. Then $U(\cdot,\cdot,s)$ will map this example's initial conditions as follows:
\begin{equation}
U(\cdot,\cdot,s):\left[\begin{array}{c}x\\0\end{array}\right]\mapsto\left[\begin{array}{c}y(s)\\s\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}
In other words,
\begin{equation}
U(x,0,s) = \left[\begin{array}{c}\Phi(x,0,s)\\s\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}

---

Let $s\mapsto\mathbf{v}(s) = [w(s),-s]^{\mathsf{T}}$ be the solution of
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{ds}\left[\begin{array}{c}w(s)\\-s\end{array}\right] &=& \left[\begin{array}{c}-b(w(s),-s)\\-1\end{array}\right] ~=~ \left[\begin{array}{c}-b(\mathbf{v}(s))\\-1\end{array}\right],\\
\mathbf{v}(0) &=& \left[\begin{array}{c}x\\0\end{array}\right].
\end{eqnarray}
This system is also autonomous.

Let $V$ be the flow of this system. Then $V(\cdot,\cdot,s)$ maps this example's initial conditions as follows:
\begin{equation}
V(\cdot,\cdot,s):\left[\begin{array}{c}x\\0\end{array}\right]\mapsto\left[\begin{array}{c}w(s)\\-s\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}
In other words,
\begin{equation}
V(x,0,s) = \left[\begin{array}{c}\Psi(x,0,s)\\-s\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}

---

Since $U$ is the flow of an autonomous system, $U(\cdot,\cdot,s)$ pushes a solution $\mathbf{u}$ from its value *at any time* (due to the unchaning vector field) to its value $s$ time units later. The complication here is that $w(s)$ is not a fixed point.

Note, however, that at each point $(x,t)$, the vector-valued right-hand sides of the two autonomous systems differ only in sign: one is $[b(x,t),~1]^{\mathsf{T}}$ and the other is $[-b(x,t),-1]^{\mathsf{T}}$. That means a solution of one is a solution of the other run backward in time.

This implies that $V(\cdot,\cdot,s) = U(\cdot,\cdot,-s)$. This, in turn, implies that, since $[y(s),~s]^{\mathsf{T}}$ and $[w(s),-s]^{\mathsf{T}}$ started at the same point ($[x,~0]^{\mathsf{T}}$) at time $0$ and evolved according to opposite-pointing vector fields, $w(s) = y(-s)$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\Phi(\Psi(x,0,s),0,s) &=& \Phi(w(s),0,s)\\
&=& \Phi(y(-s),0,s)\\
&=& \Phi(\Phi(x,0,-s),0,s)\\
&=& x
\end{eqnarray}

I'm sure this can be argued with much more sophistication, but I think the rough shape of the argument is clear. I apologize for the completely incorrect previous answer.

Comment: Thank you. I thought to the integral representation of $\Phi$ and $\Psi$. Indeed $\Phi(x, 0, s)=x+\int_0^sb(y(\tau), \tau)d\tau$ and, according to $(\triangle)$, $\Psi(x, 0, s)=x-\int_0^sb(y(\tau), t-\tau)d\tau$, right? So, if I compute, for example, $\Phi(\Psi(x, 0, s), 0, s)$, it should be $x-\int_0^sb(y(\tau), t-\tau)d\tau+\int_0^sb(y(\tau), \tau)d\tau$ which is not equal to $x$..

Comment: @Redeldio: I agree with you. $(\triangle)$ does not define a flow inverse to $\Phi$, as you have demonstrated in your comment. Since $t$ appears explicitly in the definition of $\Psi(x,0,s)$, _i.e._ in a symbol that does have $t$ in it, I suspect strongly that the instructor made a typographical error.

Comment: Yes, I think the same. So, what should be the correct $(\triangle)$? Maybe $y'(s)=-b(y(s), s)$, $y(0)=x$?

Comment: This idea is wrong, starting with $Φ(y(−s),0,s)$ being something simple. The only valid equation in that direction is  $Φ(y(−s),-s,s)=y(0)$. What you wrote is only correct if the ODE is autonomous.

Comment: @lutz-lehmann is absolutely right. Due to the explicit time-dependence of $b$, the system is not autonomous, so my argument does not work.

Comment: @Redeldio: I have re-written my argument for the associated autonomous system. It's not the prettiest you will ever see, but I think you can clean it up to be presentable.

Comment: @JoeMack thank you. Now it's more clear. About the integral representation, how can I write $\Phi(\Phi(x, 0, -s), 0, s)$? Is it $x+\int_0^{-s}b(y(\tau), \tau)d\tau+\int_0^sb(y(\tau), \tau)d\tau$?

Comment: @Redeldio: I think that's correct. But I think you'll have more flexibility using the autonomous system view and making arguments using its properties. Relying on integral expressions can get very messy.

Comment: @JoeMack Yes, argumenting using autonomous system is better. But I think that $\int_0^{-s}b(y(\tau), \tau)d\tau+\int_0^sb(y(\tau), \tau)d\tau$ is not equal to $0$. Maybe in the first integral $b$ has to be written as $b(y(-\tau), -\tau)$ and then concluding with a change of variable, right?

Comment: @Redeldio: Near the end, everything is expressed in terms of $\Phi$ and the solution $y$ alone; we have removed all references to $\Psi$ and the solution $w$. The right-hand side for $\Phi$ is $b(y(s),s)$.

Comment: Ok, but I cannot understand why $\int_0^{-s}b(y(\tau), \tau)d\tau+\int_0^sb(y(\tau), \tau)d\tau$ is equal to $0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116527/discussion-between-joe-mack-and-redeldio).